# File Download on NodeJS with use opensubtitles API

Tags: node.js, file, download, character-encoding, subtitle

I'm new user for NodeJS and JS. I'm using NodeJS for make my Web API project. My Project using opensubtitles API. Opensubtitles api give me a .*gz file URL. I want save to local folder file on this URL. I tried a few methods. But I was not successful. I downloaded file on local folder but some language characters come out corrupted.

**Sample file Url:**

https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-19ed0c61/filead/1954767944.gz

If I download it with a web browser, the characters are coming out properly.

**My sample code:**

```
const out = fs.createWriteStream('out.srt'); 
request(subtitle.getSubDownloadLink()).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(out);
```

Comment: Do you know the right datacoding of the file?

Comment: There are a few different types. Example: utf8 or cp1254... this example subtitle file language is Turkish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the charset output (default utf8)

So you need to convert the strreamed file from `iso-8859-5` (charset of the file in gz) to `utf8`.

This works:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const request = require('request')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var converterStream = iconv.decodeStream('iso-8859-5');

const out = fs.createWriteStream('out.srt');
request(`https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-19ed0c61/filead/1954767944.gz`)
  .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
  .pipe(converterStream)
  .pipe(out);
```